# How to loop through rows in mysql table and delete those which have a certain value in a given field?

Tags: mysql, field, sql-delete

I have a mysql table with rows containing an integer field and from the PHP script, I need to delete those rows in table which have a **field value (integer) lower than $minimum** - how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE field < ?
```